# Independence of ordered random variables with other ordered variables?

Tags: probability

I realize this might be silly, but suppose I have some discrete random variables that are all independent of each other. Call them $X_1,\dots, X_n, Y_1, \dots Y_m$. Each forms a discrete uniform distribution.

Now if I sort by value the $X$'s into $X_{(1)},\dots,X_{(n)}$ (and vice versa for the $Y$'s), then how do I confirm that any $X_{(i)}$ is indeed independent of any $Y_{(j)}$? Is this possible? Have I completely mistaken what this sorting means? I realize the sorted random variables will have different distributions depending on the $n$ and $m$, but I can't square any of this information with the definition for independence.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then so are $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$.

Here, $(X_1,\cdots,X_n)$ is independent of $(Y_1,\cdots,Y_m)$. Moreover $X_{(i)}$ is a function of $(X_1,\cdots,X_n)$, and $Y_{(j)}$ is a function of $(Y_1,\cdots,Y_m)$. Therefore $X_{(i)}$ and $Y_{(j)}$ are independent.